# An unexpected error has occurred while verifying the form template

Tags: infopath

I have a form that I am able to publish successfully on one server but when i try and deploy to the live server. It give an error when checking the logs i get this error:

> Deployment failed conversion, or design checker found fatal errors:
>   An unexpected error has occurred while verifying the form template.

I am completely stuck, any ideas?